# How to Align smaller text on top of larger text

Tags: html, css

I have three text items in a container. The middle text has the larger font. I would like to align the top the first item to the top of the second item.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.large {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="first">One</p>
    <p class="large">Two</p>
    <p>Three</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ofrravh/2/

The only way I can think of to do this is to use absolute position but this gets out of line when I change the screen size. I want to be able to change the size of the screen and have everything stay in place. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change CSS:

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin:0;
}

.large {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height:1;
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin:0;
}

.large {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height:1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="first">One</p>
    <p class="large">Two</p>
    <p>Three</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the edited version of your code

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
}
.container p.first {
  vertical-align:top;
  line-height:40px;
}

.large {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="first">One</p>
    <p class="large">Two</p>
    <p>Three</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change the code to look more like this:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
}

.large {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height:1;
}
  
.first {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="first">One</p>
    <p class="large">Two</p>
    <p>Three</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do it: https://jsfiddle.net/7ofrravh/5/ .
By making *container* flexible with content alignment an the start by using `align-items: flex-start` . Then simply fixing first paragraph position with a `margin: 10px 0 0 0`.